# A word describes the person who tends to stereotype people

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adjectives, pejorative-language

Is there a word/adjective (single word) that describes the person who likes consiously or uncousiously to stereotype people? I was thinking that there might be a word such as *stereotypist*, but such a word does not exist. The word I'm expecting should describe the type of people who are very interested in general backgrounds to prejudge. Of course I eliminate *racist* as the word I'm looking for includes people who prejudge even based on the gender. The kind of person who asks about age, religion, gender, race or political view  before he makes a decision in which corner in his circle will he locate you, no matter how differet/unique you are.

Comment: A stereotypist is someone who presses keys with both hands.

Comment: I think you are trying to stereotype somebody.

Comment: @andy256 I was about to say I'm afraid I belong to this kind of people by asking such a question :)

Comment: @Hawk This description could easily be applied to every human that's ever lived. We all categorize everything we encounter. No one is so special that they are uncategorizable.

Comment: why not judgemental?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Bigot* or *prejudiced* come to mind. Bigot is a much more negative term, but even prejudiced has mostly negative connotations.

Answer (score 1):

This person is what I would call *intolerant*. Intolerant people are generally exclusive of others instead of inclusive.

Answer (score -2):

*Presumptuous* or *pretentious* are two possible words to describe with.

Comment: Neither work. *Presumptuous* is too general while *pretentious* has a completely unrelated meaning.

Comment: When one is pretentious with their presumptions they can be stereotypical.  This may be a stereotype.

Comment: Presumptuous is a good answer, because it is a personality trait of people who make lazy, false assumptions.