# What is a adjective to describe someone stereotyping on a specific person?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've been wondering about this for a while, and the question didn't really come out right. The word, "stereotypical", i have been wanting to use for someone who often stereotypes someone. Let me give you an example. If someone was to say, "All boys are uneducated"(which they aren't, by the way), then my response would be, "That is very stereotypical of you", but of course that is not the right way to use this word. I know the word stereotypical means, (according to google) "relating to a widely held but fixed and oversimplified image or idea of a particular type of person or thing" but i thought it meant a word to describe some one making generalizations or stereotypes on a specific person.

Comment: See this [similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205106/a-word-describes-the-person-who-tends-to-stereotype-people) which recommends _bigot, prejudiced, intolerant_ amongst other words.

Comment: You mean a person who typecasts someone in a particular stereotype?

Comment: Your Google reference is a bit simplistic but broadly, *stereotypical* does  mean *relating to a widely held but fixed and oversimplified idea of a type of person or thing* and broadly no, it isn't a word to describe someone making generalizations or stereotypes about anything.

Answer (score 0):

Might be that person is **profiling** (though it's not an adjective but a verb).
it might be a **bigot** as well (though that word denotes racism as well).
looking at your example i would go with **generalizing** (though again its a verb not an adjective), and say 'you are making a **generalization**'.

Comment: Generalizing and stereotyping are not the same. E.g. if you say "he's black, so he must be a criminal", and I respond with "you're generalizing", then I'm saying that **on average, statistically, your assumption is true** (just maybe not for this particular person). Stereotyping, on the other hand, does not imply that the assumption is correct in a broad general sense, it's closer in meaning to "blind attribution".

Comment: To avoid a minefield: Stereotypes are often created when a sufficient amount of people considers something to be (sufficiently) correct. That means that a stereotype **may or may not** have been a correct generalization when it was created. It would be correct to say that **some stereotypes are generalizations**, but not _all_ stereotypes are generalizations. Since we cannot know for sure that this is the case for the OP's current stereotype, I would avoid "generalization".